# D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to add the below dependencies:

```yaml
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.7
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+5
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.3
  image_picker: ^0.6.1+8
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
  firebase_storage: ^3.0.6
  cached_network_image: 2.0.0-rc.1
  firebase_messaging: 6.0.13
  flutter_local_notifications: 1.4.0
  photo_view: ^0.5.0
```

I found this error:

```
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 85948 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:      
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.       
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:131)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:118)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:444)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:335)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:47)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:65)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:56)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:215)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:210)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:55)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:116)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 85948 > 65536)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:21)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:7)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile.a(:33)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile$h.a(:5)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.a(:13)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.write(:35)        
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(:44)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:23)
        ... 36 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
     The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
     Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 51s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        53.6s
[!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.
    To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.
    To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

and this is my full `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
name: aradi_online_vtwo
description: A new Flutter project.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^3.0.0
  intl: ^0.15.8
  flutter_speed_dial: ^1.2.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  smooth_star_rating: ^1.0.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.7
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+5
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.3
  image_picker: ^0.6.1+8
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
  firebase_storage: ^3.0.6
  cached_network_image: 2.0.0-rc.1
  firebase_messaging: 6.0.13
  flutter_local_notifications: 1.4.0
  photo_view: ^0.5.0

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/design_course/
    - assets/fitness_app/
    - assets/hotel/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: WorkSans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/WorkSans-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/WorkSans-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/WorkSans-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/WorkSans-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
    - family: Roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf
          weight: 400
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

So how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Add multiDex to your app-level build.gradle file.
Under defaultConfig add this line

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Then in dependencies add multidex and check versions

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex: 2.0.1'
```

Comment: I tried 'multiDexEnabled' only, and that worked. But I don't think it's needed. Simply set 'minSdkVersion 21' and will do the job for you.

Comment: This could be a new development but the answer above  allows you to use referenced libraries with above 65,536 methods. Could be an android generation issue.

Answer (score 22):

So basically this error happens when your app and the libraries it references exceed 65,536 methods,the build error just means your app has reached the limit of the Android build architecture, so to fix this go to `android/app/build.gradle` directory and add the `multiDexEnabled true` and `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'` in thus manner

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        ........
        multiDexEnabled true
    }


dependencies {
    ...........
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

and of course restart your android-studio or the platform you're using.

Answer (score 18):

**Upgrade min sdk to 21**

I had the same issue and Multi dex is not engouh to solve it
I'm solve it with updgrading min sdk to 21

```
 defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    multiDexEnabled
}



 dependencies {
     ...
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

Comment: you just need to update the minSdkVersion to be 21 as explained by the official Firebase team on this video on minute 04:45 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXp0gq9kGxI  . you don't need `implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'`

Comment: `multiDexEnabled true ` enough and change to  `minSdkVersion 21`

Comment: Solved for me by simply changing the minSdkVersion to 21. No other changes required.

Answer (score 2):

Easier way to enable multidexing is running -

```
flutter run --debug
```

on the command line. When prompted just enter `y`

Comment: Can't believe this answer is not paid attention. This is obviously a better and more robust answer.

Answer (score 1):

If none of this works just add one more thing increment  your minsdkversion in app gradle (build gradle ) if it is 20 then do 21 or increase by 1 -2 . It works for me

Answer (score 0):

in my case the app not build after adding the above lines so I have

```
           shrinkResources true
           minifyEnabled true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

       }
       debug {
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

           minifyEnabled true
           shrinkResources true
       }
```

proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
line is missing so I add it

Answer (score 0):

If you use android plugin with version `7.4.0`, you need to add `minifyEnabled true` to `debug{}` block.

`id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0'`

```
buildTypes {
        release { ... }
        debug {
            // 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0' 需要（奇葩）
            minifyEnabled true

            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
        }
    }
```