# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > No matching client found for package name 'com.example.myapp '

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, dart

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> No matching client found for package name 'com.example.myapp '

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

This is a client portion from Google Service.json

"client": [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766493/execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebuggoogleservices-no-matching-clien
{

```
  "client_info": {

"mobilesdk_app_id": "1:110944006455:android:f790b09ad0563a63046ab2",
"android_client_info": {
  "package_name": "com.example.myapp"
}
}
```

And here is my build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.riderapp "
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

You can see that the application ID for both is same.
Yet I receiver this error:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task `:app:processDebugGoogleServices`

> No matching client found for package name 'com.example.myapp'

Comment: have you implemented google services in build.gradle? classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The application Id for both is not the same. In google services json it says `com.example.myapp`

But in your buildGradle it's `com.example.riderapp`

Go to firebase, add your app again with the name used in buildGradle `com.example.riderapp`, add your SHA-1 debug key to firebase in this step also, then download your json again and remove the old one. And report back what happens.

Note: make sure to keep the new googlejson named exactly `google-services.json`

Comment: I forgot I am using gadle applicationIdSuffix to my variant project type and I choose for debug(not same as google-service.json application id, thank you!

Comment: @ChrisHo similar case for me, how to build different variant then

Comment: @VikasPandey Just make sure your current package name need exact same as google-service.json setting package name.

Comment: @ChrisHo yes, that part I understood.
It seems like there should be different firebase project for every application id we want to have and then that many google services json file.
Is there a simpler way, I am looking for a solution where I just need to have only one google service json file with all the client ( applicationId ) info.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** As @Huthaifa Muayyad said application Ids are not the same, you can do as he said or the more straightforward way is to change the *"package_name"* in *google-services.json* to "com.example.riderapp",

**Reason:** This error happens when you share your project with your teammate who might have a different project name, so we need to change the package_name to our project name.

Even After this, there might be errors as
*"ERROR:D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 97652 > 65536) com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K."* which you can resolve as said in this answer [D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62223356/d8-cannot-fit-requested-classes-in-a-single-dex-file) by @king mort

Answer (score 1):

Your Android [React Native] Project Bundle id is different from firebase project bundle ID, Create new app on firebase or change your app local bundle id with same as it is on firebase

Answer (score -1):

change minSdkVersion to 21 in app/build.gradle
and change every 'com.example.anything' in your project to you project id (you can find it in project details in firestore)